# Google PubSub future.get() runs forever

Tags: java, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

publisher.publish(message).get() runs forever when executed in a docker container.

But it works fine and publishes the messages to the topic when executed in local IDE eclipse

I tried calling future.get through an Executor service. The program gets completed but doesn't publish the message to the topic.

Comment: Can you provide the full code for your publisher? Also, how long is "forever"? By default, a publish call will retry on retryable errors for up to 10 minutes. So if you stopped your client manually before that, you wouldn't see an error on the publish.